# my c code crashes when running it on c-free but works fine on borland?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, turbo-c

when running my code in borland c 3.1 it works fine, but when running it on c-free it crashes at this line: `while(ptr1->pright)
       {
       ptr1=ptr1->pright;
       }`
giving SIGSEGV, any logical reasons?

Comment: Your code almost certainly has a memory issue, so it exhibits an undefined behavior: it happens to not crash on Borland, but that's a pure coincidence.

Comment: Maybe ptr1 is uninitialized.

Comment: The problem is with the code that builds/manipulates the linked list. You should examine it (or post it here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably accessing memory outside the bounds of an array or which you didn't allocate. As such, you triggered **undefined behaviour**, so pretty much anything can happen, including crashing or even *apparently* working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When creating/initialising your linked list's nodes make sure to explicitly initialise the node's member `pright` to `NULL`.